# Is there a difference between 生出 and 生産？

Tags: meaning, nuances

I checked the definitions in here for [生産](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E7%94%9F%E7%94%A3_%28%E3%81%9B%E3%81%84%E3%81%95%E3%82%93%29/#jn-121550) and [生出](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E7%94%9F%E5%87%BA/#jn-121790) and there appears to be a huge overlap between the two words. That said, what is the major difference between these two?

Comment: Is it 出生 or 生出 that you're interested in?

Comment: It's 生出. Sorry if I caused any confusion. But feel free to add 出生 to the mix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**産出【さんしゅつ】**: production (of natural resources and agricultural crops)

- 中国は小麦の産出量で世界一だ。
- 石油の産出で有名な国。

**生産【せいさん】**: production (mainly for industrial products, but also for natural resources and crops)

- この工場では車の部品を生産している。
- 中国は小麦の生産量で世界一だ。

<sub>(Strictly speaking, as defined in the dictionary you checked, 生産 can be used for human reproduction in highly academic contexts. For example 総再生産率 means [gross reproduction rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_reproduction_rate). But not many native speakers are familiar with this usage, and it's wise to always avoid using 生産 for humans unless you are talking with experts.)</sub>

**出生【しゅっせい】**: birth

- 王子の出生を祝うパーティーが開かれた。
- 日本の出生数は低下傾向だ。

<sub>(出産 is also "birth" but it's closer to medical "delivery" as the last process of pregnancy.)</sub>

**輩出【はいしゅつ】**: production (of capable people from school)

- この大学は多数の政治家を輩出している。

---

**生出【せいしゅつ】** is an old word and it's extremely rare in modern Japanese. You probably don't have to remember this. (My IME and I did not know this.)

Comment: 生出 might be a psuedo-Sino-Japanese compound that derives from 生み出す. It'd sound weird in the Chinese sense of the character 生.